# When should kieSession be disposed?

Tags: java, drools, kie

I have a batch processing code that uses drools to run some validation checks. Originally, I made one kieSession for the whole app and used it in the code that reads the data. Below is a pseudo code:

```
private KieSession kieSession=new DroolsBeanFactory().getKieSession(DROOLS_FILE_PATH);;
public void func(){
    //..
    kieSession.insert(data);
    kieSession.setGlobal("data", data);
    kieSession.fireAllRules();
    //..
}
```

This way, I get an `OutOfMemoryError` after some time. Looks like a memory leak?
When I add `kieSession.dispose()` after `fireAllRules()` and again initialize the `kieSession`, the heap gets cleared as expected and no error occurs.

But this way, I end up initializing kieSession in each method call. This slows down my app. I tried re-initializing on every 1000th call, it works but I am not sure if this is the right way.

What should be done in this situation?

Comment: Stateful or stateless session? Also globals should be avoided, that's a very old-fashioned way of writing rules ... not surprised you run out of memory eventually.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas the KieSession class is extending StatefulRuleSession, so I am assuming this is stateful. I am new to drools framework, can you suggest what is the standard way of writing rules? If you have any examples, please share.

Comment: @PiyushShrivastava do you delete your data or only insert it? Insertion creates strong references just like HashMap or other collection. Don't you expect OOME while inserting objects to the same collection with application life cycle?